# javascript / php - change textfields based on select change

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to change several textfields every time I select a new option in my select option. This is the code I currently have, any ideas where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#combo").change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.get(document, {type: value});
            });
        </script>


        <td class="bold"><label for='addType'>Select Type to Add : </label>
            <select name="addType" id="combo">
                <option value="book">Book</option>
                <option value="author">Author</option>
                <option value ="publisher">Publisher</option>
                <option value="customer">Customer</option>
            </select>
        <?php
            $type['type'] = $_GET['type'];
            if ($type['type'] == 'author') {
                print "test";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: but you did not enter this in just one file? you have the php part seperated from your html/javascript?

Comment: It is in one file, do I need to inclose the everything in php tags?

Comment: Your get .get() has no callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The $.get function should look something like this:

```
 $.get("php_page.php", 
       {type: value},
       function(data) {
             $("#response").html(data)
      );
```

After your `</select>` place a div with id "response" that will show your returned value:

```
 <div id="response">
 </div>
```

Now all you need to do is create a second page in the same directory ("php_page.php") which will handle your $.get AJAX request:

```
<?php
      echo $_GET['type'];
?>
```

And in case you don't know, PHP is a server-side language.  This means that once the page loads, the PHP has already done its work.  So if you need to use the special PHP powers after the page has loaded, that's what AJAX is for.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get it figured out from here!

Comment: As mentioned above, the `$.ajax` function is typically the standard for ajax calls, so you could use that instead of `$.get`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this the **completely wrong way!!** Please read the manual about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on jQuery.

*Just for helping you start your project:*

You have to seperate the basic structure from your response you want to get from your php file. Please see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/zVkBh/)**

The HTML part is:

```
<select name="addType" id="combo">
    <option value="book">Book</option>
    <option value="author">Author</option>
    <option value ="publisher">Publisher</option>
    <option value="customer">Customer</option>
</select>
<div>Response: <span id="selection"></span></div>
```

This could also be filled with PHP but is not the response!

The JavaScript is:

```
$("#combo").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/html/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"html":"Yeah: "+$(this).val()+" is cool!"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#selection").html(data);
        }
    });
});​
```

it would be nice if you put this in an extra file.

last but not least the *"PHP file"* specified with the url `/echo/html` does following:

```
<?php
  echo $_POST["html"];
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! One question on the url though. If I have this file and the php_page.php on the same level, the url would just be "php_page.php" right?

Comment: Yes! This 'echo/html' is only necessary for the jsfiddle demo, because you can not update a php file there :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, this section:

```
<?php
    $type['type'] = $_GET['type'];
    if ($type['type'] == 'author') {
        print "test";
}?>
```

will only print when the page first loads, and only if type=xxx is in the url query string. You cant run PHP on the page itself after it loads since the code is server-side

for the jquery part, try:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#combo').change(function(){doAjax();});
    }
);
function doAjax(){
    $.get(
        'url', //i think jquery defaults to self if not url is given but you can also use <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
        {'type' : $('#combo').val()},
        function(data){
                // what should the ajax call do with the response data?
        },
        "html"
    );
}
```

also you should make a div to put the returned data into with .html(), its alot easier than trying to append the response to the end of whatever was the last element above it.

Comment: I will try to implement this if I cannot get the other example figured out. Thanks!